# Failed to introspect Class org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, shiro

I hava a Spring Boot project，which use shiro provid security service。
My Shiro configuration is as below：

```
@Configuration
public class ShiroConf {
    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shirFilter(SecurityManager securityManager) {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**", "authc");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/login");     
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl("/homepage/index");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/403");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);
        return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityManager securityManager() {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(customRealm());
        securityManager.setRememberMeManager(rememberMeManager());
        securityManager.setSessionManager(defaultWebSessionManager());
        securityManager.setCacheManager(cacheManager());
        return securityManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthCustomRealm customRealm() {
        AuthCustomRealm customRealm = new AuthCustomRealm();
        customRealm.setCredentialsMatcher(hashedCredentialsMatcher());
        return customRealm;
    }
    @Bean
    public HashedCredentialsMatcher hashedCredentialsMatcher() {
        HashedCredentialsMatcher hashedCredentialsMatcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher();
        hashedCredentialsMatcher.setHashAlgorithmName("md5");
        hashedCredentialsMatcher.setHashIterations(3);
        hashedCredentialsMatcher.setStoredCredentialsHexEncoded(true);
        return hashedCredentialsMatcher;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor(SecurityManager securityManager) {
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        return authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleCookie rememberMeCookie() {
        SimpleCookie simpleCookie = new SimpleCookie("rememberMe");
        simpleCookie.setMaxAge(259200);
        return simpleCookie;
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieRememberMeManager rememberMeManager() {
        CookieRememberMeManager cookieRememberMeManager = new CookieRememberMeManager();
        cookieRememberMeManager.setCookie(rememberMeCookie());
        return cookieRememberMeManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ShiroDialect shiroDialect() {
        return new ShiroDialect();
    }

    @Bean(name="sessionManager")
    public DefaultWebSessionManager defaultWebSessionManager() {
        DefaultWebSessionManager sessionManager = new DefaultWebSessionManager();
        sessionManager.setCacheManager(cacheManager());
        sessionManager.setGlobalSessionTimeout(1000*3600*24);
        sessionManager.setSessionValidationSchedulerEnabled(true);
        sessionManager.setSessionValidationInterval(1800000);
        sessionManager.setDeleteInvalidSessions(true);
        sessionManager.setSessionDAO(sessionDAO());
        return sessionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sessionDAO")
    public CYSessionDAO sessionDAO(){
        CYSessionDAO CYSessionDAO = new CYSessionDAO();
        CYSessionDAO.setActiveSessionsCacheName("shiro-activeSessionCache");
        CYSessionDAO.setCacheManager(cacheManager());
        return CYSessionDAO;
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManager cacheManager() {
        EhCacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCacheManagerConfigFile("classpath:config/ehcache.xml");
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

After I click the run button，the project cannot run successfully and give me information：

2020-03-10 18:22:33.289  WARN 20060 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shirFilter' defined in class path resource [heyin/es/offlineweb/shiro/ShiroConf.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor' defined in class path resource [heyin/es/offlineweb/shiro/ShiroConf.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [heyin/es/offlineweb/shiro/ShiroConf.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager]: Factory method 'securityManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rememberMeManager' defined in class path resource [heyin/es/offlineweb/shiro/ShiroConf.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.CookieRememberMeManager]: Factory method 'rememberMeManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rememberMeCookie' defined in class path resource [heyin/es/offlineweb/shiro/ShiroConf.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ***Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]***

It is just a simple web project. Why would this happen?

My version is：

```
     <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
```

Comment: Have you tried the latest Shiro version?

Comment: @ Brian Demers.Thanks!      I have tried~But it didn't work and gave me one error like that above.

Comment: Can you paste the full stacktrace you see in the latest version (in a code block).  Is there anymore to that stacktrace? or maybe another log message?

Comment: Have you tried using another JVM (e.g. adopt-openj9)? Introspection sounds like either a JVM-, spring- or APM-related problem.